# Adobe Flex help with accessing database for mobile web?

Tags: database, apache-flex, jquery-mobile

Thanks in advance for any help.  Here is the issue: a client wants his entire equipment inventory accessible by persons navigating to his jquery mobile site.  The inventory that exists on the desktop site was, as I understood, built with Flex.

Is it possible to access this database for the jquery mobile site?  I believe it is.  I was then given this information from someone in the know:

> > Database:
> >
> > mlxx.db.xxxxxxx.hostedresource.com
> >
> > login: mxxx
> >     Pass: dmxxxxx
> >
> > DSN:
> >     mssql_mlxx.dsn
> >
> > Cold Fusion DSN:
> >     mssqlcf_mlxx

But I have no idea where to go from here.  If you could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.  I haven't done too much server side work which is why my question is probably really comprehensive.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an interpretation of the access data, It sounds like the data is stored in a SQL Server database, and accessed from ColdFusion.

In theory you can reuse the ColdFusion services that the Flex/AIR app uses from a HTML/JavaScrript website.

Without a full code review, I don't think we'll be able to give you any more specifics than that.

Comment: do you think this is possible to execute using what is available in the embed code?  For example, I can see that this parameter from the object tag `<param name="flashvars" value="rootID=0&rootLabel=Rental Catalog" />` gives me the parent as its rootID is 0.  Is there a way I can use this information to reinterpret in js?  Thanks

Comment: Instead of passing those values as FlashVars to a Flash Application, pass them as URL Variables to an HTML Page.